# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable in while loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, int

I need some quick help,
I've been having this problem:
"TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" at line 8
in this code:

```
sold = 0
max = 0

for i in range(0,5):
    print ("Scout",(i+1),"> ",end="")
    x = int(input())
    sold = sold + x
   for i in x:
       if i > max:
           max = i
print (max)
```

Can anyone help or rearrange this for me? Im trying to make python find the maximum value from the value x.

Comment: You casted the input to be integer and assigned it to `x`. 2 lines down, you tried to retrieve every object from `x` one by one. But what objects is integer supposed to have?

Comment: Why do you have two `i`'s? You should change the 2nd `i` variable to something else to avoid code confusion.

Comment: `for i in range()` and `for i in x` - See a problem there anywhere? Read the code you write. Also read the words in the error message: *'int' object is not iterable" at line 8* - they tell you exactly what the problem is and exactly where it is located. The message doesn't exist just to take up space on your screen.

Comment: Downvote: Your question title asks about "while" loops but your code is a "for" loop. 2 different things!  Time wasted

Answer (score 0):

How about you add the values to a list like this:

```
nums = []
```

Then instead of

```
x = int(input())
```

Put

```
nums.append(int(input())
```

Then try

```
for x in nums:
    If x > max:
        max = x
```

And make sure you get your indents right. In python, indents determine if the code runs or not and even if the indent is off by one, it will create an error or an unintended side effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd rearrange that

```
v = []  # create a list where you can store all the values
for i in range(5):
    print("Scout {} > ".format(i + 1), end="")
    v.append(int(input()))  # read it and append it to the end of the list
print(max(v))  # your 'max' variable
print(sum(v))  # your 'sold' variable
```

Note that naming variable `max` is usually a bad idea, because it overrides the built-in function I've just used.

Comment: Your code seems about right but I had a problem in line 5 where it says that the 'int' object is not callable.

Comment: You asked "Can anyone help or rearrange this for me?". I chose the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shortened and working version of your code:

```
v = [int(input("Scout {} > ".format(i + 1))) for i in range(5)]
print('max: {}'.format(max(v)))
print('sold: {}'.format(sum(v)))
```